# What alternative methods are available for overclocking?

Tags: bios, overclocking

I'm aware that overclocking software isn't exactly the best way to overclock your hardware, but I am not sure what else to do. I have a HP computer, which has HP's BIOS which eliminates a possibility that I could OC in the BIOS.

I tried downloading AMD's overdrive to overclock my ATI 6490m, but I have an Intel i5-2410m CPU, and so that wound up crashing my system. I looked at the Intel Desktop Control Center, but it seems it is only available for select desktop mobos, and I am running a laptop. Is there any chance that I can overclock my system, even a little, or am I stuck with what I've got?

Comment: OOC why do you want to overclock your system?  even overclocking doesnt really yield significantly faster systems, just a few percent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty much stuck with what you got. Also, I wouldn't recommend overclocking a laptop - the components are packed into a pretty limited space, any additional heat beyond what manufacturer expected can.. cause problems

Answer (score 0):

You can check out http://www13.plala.or.jp/setfsb/

It's a overclocking program that will need to be configured on each boot. I've written some startup scripts to enable the overclocking on boot. This way you can tweak your settings and find a stable environment before making it a "permanent" change.